# Voltage across capacitor measured in parallel, why not showing Vc?

Tags: capacitor, ac, measurement, voltage-measurement, output

I am trying to understand something and missing something. In a low pass RC filter, the output is connected in parallel with the capacitor, right, and is phase shifted, because the current in a RC filter is phase shifted, the current is the derivative of the voltage or it is flowing when the voltage is changing, not at the peaks. But, if the output is in parallel with the capacitor, it provides a path for electricity that bypasses the capacitor. It seems like it would prefer to flow at the peaks, when the capacitor fully charged. Yet, if the output has the same type of 90° phase shift, this cannot be the case. Why?

Attaching a little drawing showing a low pass RC filter, and then one with a resistor connected in parallel to the capacitor, assuming the current through it would be analogous to the output circuit whether it is a voltmeter or such or something receiving the filtered signal.

[image]

If I [simulate and test](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDMB0YEwFYCmBaA7FAHHaaBsi2YALJAJxkAMexICldIpdqYYAUAMZNl7hlwefXiAaVolSZRIVZc%20WRApxaBAjjSymVXEiU0mWijCV2ANxBw4tMAMvWQIhhBOMxo6AnYAne7RHEIk7g7MSUkEpgeAzEmPyCtoJiAPom1smUyWEUyTgIGRLw%20ZlwGcmQoeGR0Uo08UxxzqmU6ZnZZMn5eNDEqbl9FQDudMT%20fIHCfKbDE-UIo-WmvvNjIzZ2zpURxvj1iVDqoiBoza1ZlDl55dClJcknQ0L1VutJ7JCNR%20JSkhDfv9IQABhACGAAcQZwAJYAFxBADtOEh2EA) on falstad.com, the current over the parallel resistor seems to follow the voltage source (or capacitor that also follows it), and not the change in voltage like the current into the capacitor does.

So what I am wondering is why voltage measured in parallel still follows current into capacitor when it does not if picked apart like I did here. And I assume it must since otherwise low pass RC filters would not have phase shift as they do.

Comment: The capacitor still takes time to charge and the voltage across the cap and resistor must be the same, You also talk about peaks, but which peak? Because if the capacitor takes time to charge, that means that the voltage peak is always lagging behind the current peak.

Comment: I am missing something still. From AC voltage peak, as it goes down, there is a voltage gradient from capacitor to AC generator driving current. But there must be a much bigger voltage gradient across the parallel resistor between the poles of the capacitor.

Comment: I have no problem understanding the amplitude drop in high pass and low pass RC filters, but this I don't get at all.

Comment: Please name your resistors so I can talk about them properly. That still doesn't change the fact that the capacitor still needs to charge up and still charges up through the resistor. Therefore the voltage across the other resistor is still cannot run away from the cap.

Comment: your first unedited comment was better. naming the resistors might be a bit overkill since clearly you are chatting with someone who is not at an expert level, and using expert detail is usually 1) overkill and 2) even making matters worse, in that case. but if you want me to name them call them R1 or R2 maybe or Rinput and Routput, I don't really care.

Comment: I appreciate all feedback I just assume I must be missing something very easy, because it has always been the case so far in my life

Comment: I think it's just that I misinterpret the capacitor being a voltage gradient. If an electron where to leave the negatively charged side, it would be "pulled back" by the positively charged side, instead of being able to transfer along the wire and resistor. Or, the same voltage that would drive current over the parallel resistor, is also driving current "over the dielectric", although it cannot pass it. So it adds up to 0.

Comment: Maybe enter it into Falstead circuit simulator and watch it run through things slowly. I have been assuming that by gradient you just mean "voltage difference" in which case every component in the circuit has a voltage difference across it.

Comment: I have simulated it. Agree that is a good approach. But I am missing something. When the capacitor is fully charged it blocks current but the parallel resistor does not. Compare with a DC equivalent. No current through capacitor, but constant through resistor.

Comment: I guess I'll just keep watching this until I get what I was wondering about, https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWc0BMYAcKAsBOAzDgGyQDskeWJeIxISW1CApgLRhgBQAbuLWCul6QQKSIOEQswpMNnQEHAE5DwAkSRSrx4eBwDG6zf0EoNIsVCix4EMPNw4UhKgjzocOElbicA7iDwEIzVTYPEOf0DNURMzGKgIw3NBMFp4yCUAoK0s6IsJdDgOAHtLQixLKQ8dbxQZGktqQjKA8EsIPA4gA

Comment: I feel that what you're missing is what I said earlier where the one resistor still limits how fast the capacitor can charge, and the capacitor and other resistor must have the same voltage so it doesn't matter how much current can flow through that resistor since it is always bound by the capacitor.

Comment: The thing is that if I simulate it with Falstad, my assumption is right. The current across the parallel resistor follows the voltage source, but the current into the capacitor follows the change in voltage. https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDMB0YEwFYCmBaA7FAHHaaBsi2YALJAJxkAMexICldIpdqYYAUAO51yYiJ4efSAjghK7AMZD+CQQNmCGlaJTWUSFLdp1l+0SKTRkwNSmUh5IkNBhRgJAN0VRRLhQwgPGy8dATsAE4uImKiwm6e7MSUkCD2eAzEfGBkYqlingD6DnDEWZRZMRRZCAWq8GWFcDlZkNGx8aYMKDTgaUx8DDW5+YXFZKV10D1ZNTX13ApwlHzTcuJcMjN84S4SwdOzy9tRMXH2+O3pHaHiIJg5lHkFReaDOGUwNdVZl-WQKecq6moQP38NCAAMIAQwADqDJABLAAuoIAdpIkOwgA

Comment: That Falstad simulation has been created upside down relative to your Fig. 1. (Add captions while you're adding the component designators. The CircuitLab schematic editor - on the toolbar - will do the designators automatically for you.) The upside-down simulation results may be confusing you.

Comment: They're not "confusing" me, because they're right. And adding names is a great feature, when needed. I am not trying to win the nobel prize here, I am a noob wondering about things I'd hope people know if they know any basics. I was right in my assumption, but it isn't what I wonder about specifically. I wonder specifically why low pass filter phase shift is reverse to "pure capacitance", and increases when impedance decreases. I don't get that. Looking more at output parallel to capacitor was just a way to explore it more.

Comment: The reason people are asking you to name the resistors is so *we* can clearly refer to them without describing which resistor we are trying to talk about each time. It has nothing to do with noobness or Nobel prizes.

Comment: uhu and I am saying that I am not going in for any kind of award here. I am asking something very basic, I could name resistors back and forth, but, mostly I am going to do as I judge is best. this is a site with different people, not a dictatorship

Comment: just add name to image in question if you think it is important. I don't so I won't.

Comment: Remember, you're the one who came asking us for help, not the other way around.

Comment: there is no "us", there are different people using a site like this. measuring actual consensus among users is not really possible, and getting a feeling about it can often be wrong to. this question was not really what I am not getting anyway, and I was also right in my assumption as seen when it was modelled.

Comment: The question was a bad question, mainly. sometimes when trying to understand something you take a few bad steps. I am considering all feedback and usually have a really good learning curve on things.

Comment: That "The capacitor still takes time to charge", I get that, but not why this delay only reaches 90° at most. I do get the 90° phase shift for the high pass filter and "pure capacitance" circuit. It makes sense there.

Comment: I guess it's because it can at most reach its voltage peak as the AC voltage reaches 0. This equals 90°. So your first comment might have explained it to me. I am really not rejecting any answers or comments, I just have to get it, not just pretend to have understood.

Answer (score 2):

It may help if you simplify the circuit with the Thevenin equivalent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjeTKv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1 (a) Original, (b) rearranged and (c) equivalent.*

$$ R_5 = R_3 || R_4 = \frac {R_3 \cdot R_4}{R_3 + R_4} $$

$$ V_3 = \frac {R_4} {R_3 + R_4}V_1 $$

Now you're back to analysing your simple RC low-pass filter again.

For example, if R1 = R2 = 5 kΩ then V3 = 2.5 V and R5 = 5 kΩ.